# Which is the simple and fast UNIX command to print all lines from the last occurrence of a pattern?

Tags: perl, unix, awk, sed

Which is the simple and fast UNIX command to print all lines from the last occurrence of a pattern to the end of the file ?

```
sed -n '/pattern/,$p' file
```

This sed command prints from the first occurrence onwards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'H;/pattern/h;$!d;x;//!d' file
```

Stashes the last pattern and following lines in the hold space and at end-of-file prints them out.

Or using the same method in awk:

```
awk '{x=x ORS $0};/pattern/{x=$0};END{if(x ~ //)print x}' file
```

However on my machine jaypals way with sed seems to be the quickest:

```
tac file | sed '/pattern/q' | tac
```

Answer (score 7):

Reverse the file, print until the first pattern, exit and reverse the file.

```
tac file | awk '/pattern/{print;exit}1' | tac
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Perlish way to do it:

```
perl -ne '$seen = 1, @a = () if /pattern/; push @a, $_; END { print @a if $seen }' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest solution is just to use a regex matching on the entire file:

```
perl -0777 -ne 'print $1 if /pattern(.*?)$/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

A standalone awk:

```
awk '/pattern/{delete a;c=0}{a[c++]=$0}END{for (i=0;i<c;i++){print a[i]}}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an pure `awk`

```
awk 'FNR==NR {if ($0~/pattern/) f=FNR;next} FNR==f {a=1}a' file{,}
```

It reads the file twice, and first time set a flag for last found of `pattern`, then print form `pattern` and out.

---

Or you can store data in an array like this:

```
awk '/pattern/ {f=NR} {a[NR]=$0} END {for (i=f;i<=NR;i++) print a[i]}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk for multi-char RS and gensub():

```
$ awk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= '{print gensub(/.*(pattern)/,"\\1","")}' file
```

e.g.:

```
$ cat file
a
b
c
b
d

$ awk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= '{print gensub(/.*(b)/,"\\1","")}' file
b
d
```

The above simply deletes from the start of the file up to just before the last occurrence of "b".